# Find if listA contains any elements not in listB

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists:

```
List<int> listA     
List<int> listB
```

How to check using LINQ if in the `listA` exists an element wchich deosn't exists in the `listB` ? I can use the `foreach` loop but I'm wondering if I can do this using LINQ

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`listA.Except(listB)` will give you all of the items in listA that are not in listB

Comment: Yes, it will do this. But as this is a set based operation it's worth remembering that the resulting list will also remove duplicates present in either ListA or ListB.

Answer (score 38):

```
if (listA.Except(listB).Any())
```

Answer (score 17):

```
listA.Any(_ => listB.Contains(_))
```

:)

Comment: This is best anwser, because solutions provided by @cadrell0 and SLaks will only check if A contains all elements of B but not if B has any more elements that don't match A. This solution is valid for example below.

A: [0,1,2,3]; B: [0,1,2,3,4]
`listA.Except(listB).Any() == false`
`listA.Any(_ => listB.Contains(_)) == true`

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak True, but the question specifically asked only if A contains anything not in B - i.e. it **should** evaluate to false if B contains something not in A provided A doesn't contain something not in B. So this answer is incorrect. (Yes, I misunderstood the question when I first read.)

Comment: As you're actually using the value from Any, you shouldn't use discard ( _ ) because it means (to dev and compiler) that you don't care about value

Answer (score 9):

You can do it in a single line

```
var res = listA.Where(n => !listB.Contains(n));
```

This is not the fastest way to do it: in case `listB` is relatively long, this should be faster:

```
var setB = new HashSet(listB);
var res = listA.Where(n => !setB.Contains(n));
```

Answer (score 5):

Get the difference of two lists using [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8). The Linq `Any()` function returns a boolean if a condition is met but you can use it to return the difference of two lists:

```
var difference = ListA.Where(a => !ListB.Any(b => b.ListItem == a.ListItem)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

List has Contains method that return bool. We can use that method in query.

```
List<int> listA = new List<int>();
List<int> listB = new List<int>();
listA.AddRange(new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 });
listB.AddRange(new int[] { 3,5,6,7,8 });

var v = from x in listA
        where !listB.Contains(x)
        select x;

foreach (int i in v)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

This piece of code compares two lists both containing a field for a CultureCode like 'en-GB'. This will leave non existing translations in the list. (we needed a dropdown list for not-translated languages for articles)

`var compared = supportedLanguages.Where(sl => !existingTranslations.Any(fmt => fmt.CultureCode == sl.Culture)).ToList();`