# LINQ get elements from one collection that don't belong to another

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<MyObject> allObjects` and `List<MyObject> someObjects` (all of the objects in `someObjects` belongs to `allObjects` too. I want to get the elements from `allObjects` which doesn't belong to `someObjects` ? How can I achieve that with LINQ ?

Comment: Could you define your MyObject class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - compare two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524681/linq-compare-two-lists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's as easy as [`allObjects.Except(someObjects)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)

However, you should be aware that this uses the default equality comparer under the covers to compare the values.

If you wish to use a custom `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`, there's [an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) that allows you to do just that.

Comment: " uses the default equality comparer" just means [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
var exceptionList= allObjects.Except(someObjects);
```

Comment: please do not name variables like types... `Exception` is a Type of `System` and its better not to name some database object "exception"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
allObjects.Except(someObjects)
```