# Compare two List<string> in c# and find the duplicates

Tags: c#, list, linq, string-comparison

I've tried the methods here:

- [Compare two List<string> and print the duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148175/compare-two-liststring-and-print-the-duplicates)
- [Is there any way to compare two lists in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464413/is-there-any-way-to-compare-two-lists-in-c-sharp)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-the-set-difference-between-two-lists-linq.

None of the above solved my issue.

I have two lists, List1, and List2. List2 is a .txt file read into a string and then split into a list using commas. List1 is the output of a browser handle split using '-'. So, for example, List1 has the items "Stack Overflow", "Personal", "Microsoft Edge", and List2 has the items "Personal", and "Microsoft Edge". So, there is an overlap between the two lists. I've tried the methods below, with no success.

```
List<string> duplicates = List2.Intersect(List1).ToList();
if (duplicates.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var dup in duplicates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dup);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No");
}
```

This always will throw a no, even though I thought intersect would find ANY sort of duplicates and give it to the list. To be clear, I am hoping for the outcome "Personal" and "Microsoft Edge". I've also tried

```
bool match = List1.Contains(TextDoc);
if (match)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no Match");
}
```

TextDoc is just the txt document read into a string using File.ReadAllText. Neither of these options gives me a match, even though as far as I can tell both of them should given the context of the Lists.
Am I missing something super obvious here?

Comment: Remember: the comparisons here are sensitive both the white space and cASe. If the strings are not an EXACT match, they won't show.

Comment: "*Am I missing something super obvious here?*" -- I think the most obvious explanation is that your lists don't contain duplicates... Maybe one a different case, or has some leading/trailing whitespace, or is followed by a newline, or has some hidden unprintable Unicode characters, or something? I'd find two elements which you think should definitely be the same, and look at them very closely...

Comment: can you show your list instance?

Comment: ...or at least, a subset of the source data that includes the duplicates you were expecting to see. Consider that your parsing routine might not be doing what you were expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even though I thought intersect would find ANY sort of duplicates and give it to the list

Your thought is correct.

> Am I missing something super obvious here?

You are missing to draw the straightforward and simple conclusion: Your assumption that there are some duplicate strings between *List1* and *List2* is simply incorrect.

Inspect the strings in both lists **carefully** in the debugger. Do not trust your assumptions about what strings are in the list. You already got the evidence that there are no duplicates in both lists when the Intersect method is being invoked. Verify **very carefully** what is in both lists at the exact moment the Intersect method is being invoked.

As a side note: Also keep in mind that there are Unicode control characters that are invisible (but inspecting the strings in the debugger should reveal such control characters), and there are different Unicode characters that look similar if not identical (depending on the font used) despite being different characters. And your strings might perhaps feature one or the other, making them look the same but actually containing different character sequences, thus essentially making them unequal strings.