# Finding items of a list that are not in the other list

Tags: c#

My object is like

```
class MyObject
{
string FirstName, string LastName, string Phone
}
```

and I have two list of this object:

```
incomingList<MyObject>
fullList<MyObject>
```

How can I have a list of the things that are in the `incomingList` but are not in the `fullList`

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - compare two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524681/linq-compare-two-lists)

Comment: @cadrell0 Nop! that is a normal int type, mine is a custom type. They are different.

Comment: overload equals or supply an equality comparer.  It will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> diffs = incomingList.Except(fullList);
```

Comment: Won't compile, LINQ results are not lists unless you call `.ToList()`

Comment: This also relies on `MyObject` properly implementing equality.

Comment: @BenVoigt Correct, that's an instance where `var` would have saved my butt :) (edited)

Comment: I knew about except but doesn't even compile, that's why I posted it as question

Comment: Except is in `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @CutHimSomeSlack Then you need to be more clear in your question about what you have tried. `Except` works fine (assuming equality is implemented).

Comment: @vcsjones : Do you see it implemented in my code? No! So no it is not implemented because I don't know about it and that's probably where help is needed maybe?!!!

Answer (score 3):

[Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) is what you after

```
var result = incomingList.Except(fullList);
```

Comment: Except does not compile.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad...yeah that should work. I need some coffee :)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty no I meant CHSS's MyObject, in the OP :)