# C# and LINQ comparing specific items within two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a DTO class and a table thats converted to a list using Entity Framework.

When my page posts, it sends a list of my dto.  What I'd like to do is write code to compare the dto list with the EF list based on specific elements.  This is my code...

**MY dto**

```
public class DTOAddNewSpecialNeed
{
    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    public List<AddEditSpecialNeedList> SelectedSpecialNeeds { get; set; }
    public List<AddEditSpecialNeedList> AvailableSpecialNeeds { get; set; }
    public Guid LtcConcurrencyCheck { get; set; }

    public class AddEditSpecialNeedList
    {
        public int PersonSpecialNeedId { get; set; }
        public int SpecialNeedTypeId { get; set; }
        public string SpecialNeedDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StopDate { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My code to access... dtoSelectedList is my list of dto's passed in... my dbSelectedList is my ef object (a table) I'm comparing to.  Essentially I want to keep a list of all dto's that exist in the db (dbselectelist where the specialneedtypeid's match and specialneedtype isnt other(-12).  I also can have duplicates. Right now this code doesnt account for it.  Is there a better way to write this code or am i just doing my comparisons wrong?

```
var matchedDtos = dtoSelectedList.SelectMany(dto => dbSelectedList
                .Where(db => db.SpecialNeedTypeID == dto.SpecialNeedTypeId
                             && dto.SpecialNeedTypeId != -12)).ToList();
 var matchedOtherDtos = dtoSelectedList.SelectMany(dto => dbSelectedList
                    .Where(db => db.SpecialNeedTypeID == dto.SpecialNeedTypeId
                                 && dto.SpecialNeedTypeId == (int)SpecialNeedType.Other
                                 && db.OtherTypeText == dto.SpecialNeedDescription.Replace("Other: ", "").Trim())).ToList();
```

**My method signature where the above logic is.  The SpecialNeed class is the class generated by entity:**

```
public List<SpecialNeed> NeedsCompareDtoToDb(List<DTOAddNewSpecialNeed.AddEditSpecialNeedList> dtoSelectedList, List<SpecialNeed> dbSelectedList
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: "This isn't working, Why?" What you mean? Can you explain what you try to achieve?

Comment: Try using dto.contains(db) instead of ==

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ - compare two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524681/linq-compare-two-lists)

Comment: Hey guys, i updated the op with additional info and title change.  My comparison involves several items to compare which is where I believe im having issues, and possibly a different approach altogether.

Comment: *Right now this code doesnt account for it.* What kind of problem description is that? What *does* it do and what *should* it do?

Answer (score 1):

Write a little method,

eg

```
boolean compareDTOAndListItem(DTOAddNewSpecialNeed dto, AddEditSpecialNeedList item) {
    //comparison logic here
    if (dto.SpecialNeedTypeID != item.SpecialNeedTypeId)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Then you can easily use this method anywhere, including in LinQ queries.
You could create an extra method to compare 2 lists, or use advanced Linq queries (Join,...) to compare lists

example, find items that matches a dto

```
var dto = yourdto;
var items = yourlistofitems;
var matchingitems = items.Select(x => compareDTOAndListItem(dto, x));
```

Hope it helps..

Edit : use it to compare lists

can't you use the any Linq comparer ?

```
var listitems = allyourlistitems;
var dtos => allyourdtos;

var dtomatches = dtos.Where(d =>listitems.Any(l => compareDTOAndListItem(d, x));

var dotnotmatching = dtos.where(d => !dtomatches.Contains(d));
```

untested query typed late in the evening... but you get the idea

Comment: While that is helpful, thats what my logic code is in the op.  It's within a small function called 'CompareDtoToDb'.  This is the comparison logic that i need to know how to properly work.

Comment: I updated my op to hopefully help

Comment: I don't get you fully there. The comparison logic is specific to your application & business rules. Imho, the comparison method should simply return false at the first field comparison failure , or true at the end. so you can filter lists based on that operator method

Comment: I'm basically modifying a list to return to either insert or update to the db. But first I need to get a list that match, and a list that do not match.  Evaluate further with more business logic specific to my application, then pass the list back.

Comment: can't you use the any Linq comparer ?

    var listitems = allyourlistitems;
    var dtos => allyourdtos;

    var dtomatches = dtos.Where(d =>listitems.Any(l => compareDTOAndListItem(d, x));

    var dotnotmatching = dtos.where(d => !dtomatches.Contains(d));

untested query typed late in the evening... but you get the idea